# I am new to python and am having trouble printing an element of a list

Tags: python, list, printing

the result looks like this:

```
[([[17, 11], [57, 11], [57, 61], [17, 61]], '2', 1.0)]
```

I just want the 2 printed (second element of the list?) but keep getting "list index out of range" error.

Here is the code I am trying to use to print the list element:

```
print (result[1][0])
```

full code snippit:

```
number = 1
sresult = ''
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
for number in range (1,82):
    result = reader.readtext(datadrop+ str(number)+'.png')
    print (result[1][0])
    sresult = str(result) +sresult
print (sresult)
```

Comment: You only have one list element in your example . . . just one tuple with multiple elements in that tuple.

Comment: Use `result[0][1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list has only one tuple in it (`[(...)]`) so accessing `result[1][0]` will give an `IndexError`. You can solve by changing your code to this -

```
number = 1
sresult = ''
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
for number in range (1,82):
    result = reader.readtext(datadrop+ str(number)+'.png')
    print (result[0][1][0])
    sresult = str(result) +sresult
print (sresult)
```

I assume you want to access the second item in the tuple.

Comment: I am still getting a list index out of range error using the [0][1][0]

Comment: [([[17, 11], [57, 11], [57, 61], [17, 61]], '2', 1.0)]  ---- the value I want is the '2'

Comment: The issue may be that the first result in the range (1,82) returns a []

Answer (score 0):

this worked:

```
number = 1
sresult = ''
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
for number in range (1,82):
    result = reader.readtext(datadrop+ str(number)+'.png')
    if len(result) != 0:
        print (result[0][1][0])
    sresult = str(result) +sresult
print (sresult)
```

I had to add a way to handle empty results and used the [0][1][0] solution from sr0812